# Connecting to a Apache web server in a Docker from a remote server

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, docker

I have installed Docker in a Linux environment. Inside this host, there is a Ubuntu container running. Apache Web server is running inside this container.
I have mapped port 80 of this docker container to the host machine's port 50000.

When i try to access host machine from a remote browser, i'm unable to access it. I want to see the apache web server running on Ubuntu container.
I access like this.

http://192.168.16.3:50000

Could someone let me know what might be the cause for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to route traffic from host server port 80 to your docker container port 50000. This can be done with iptables. 
http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/08/12/docker-networking/

I ve also read that docker can run in host mode
http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/